# Replace ViewController in Storyboard while keeping Segues

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

I have a Storyboard where I have for example a UITableViewController with some incoming and outgoing Segues. Let's say I want to make this UITableViewController a UIViewController. Currently I would delete the UITableViewController, drag a UIViewController on my Storyboard and recreate all the Segues.

Alternatively, I would split my Storyboard using Xcodes Storyboard refactoring so that I at least only have to recreate all the outgoing Segues. But this cannot be done or at least is not practical in some cases where I want my ViewControllers to be in the same storyboard because they belong together.

As you know, this is cumbersome and I think it is prone to error.

**So my question is**: Can I replace a ViewController in my Storyboard without losing the incoming and outgoing Segues?

Answer (score 0):

As I know it isn't possible with IB. It's only possible to exchange the controller class name in the settings. But a UITableViewController has additional settings that wan't disappear/appear by a simple rename.

My suggestion is to create the new view controller, link the seques one by one and than remove the no longer linked UITableViewController.

(That's one of the several reasons I do not use storyboards anymore. Instead I try to implement screens independent of each other, so I can change flow and/or replace single screens more easily.)

Comment: Well I guess than the only other option would be to open the storyboard as source code and change everything manually which is even worse then recreating all the segues :/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Xcode does not have this, at least as of 9.2. The solution is to edit the storyboard file in an editor, but it's really not so bad.

Get the Object ID of the controller you want to replace, and the one that will replace it. It's in the Identity Inspector, Document section, labeled Object ID.

[image: Storyboard editor, Identity Inspector, Document section]

Make sure you save the Storyboard before editing it outside of Xcode.

Each of the segues looks like this in the storyboard file:

`<segue destination="S3O-z0-PFf" kind="showDetail" identifier="abcde2" id="x0q-y6-ZkJ"/>`

Replace the `destination` ID with the new view controller's Object ID:

`<segue destination="b5A-4F-zOe" kind="showDetail" identifier="abcde2" id="x0q-y6-ZkJ"/>`

Save the file, and Xcode will reload it automatically. The segues will point to the new controller.